# Route url is including ?=

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I'm using the following Razor in my page:

```
<a asp-action="Logs" asp-route-channel="@channel.Name">
     <button class="btn btn-success btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
</a>
```

`channel` is a string, not an integer, which is why I don't use `id`.

And this is how I'm routing it:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute("logs", "Dashboard/Logs/{channel}");
```

And in my Controller, I'm simply doing this for testing purposes:

```
public IActionResult Logs(string channel)
{
    return Content(channel);
}
```

However, when the link is generated, I get something like this:

```
<a href="/Dashboard/Logs?channel=mychannel">
```

Instead of the expected:

```
<a href="/Dashboard/Logs/mychannel">
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's what I've tried:

```
[HttpGet("{channel}")]
public IActionResult Logs(string channel)
{
    return Content(channel);
}
```

Which results in `https://localhost:44351/mychannel`

I've also tried:

```
[HttpGet("Dashboard/Logs/{channel}")]
public IActionResult Logs(string channel)
{
    return Content(channel);
}
```

Which works as intended, but why should I have to include the whole path like that?

Comment: Why not use attribute routing?

Comment: Then I have to write `[HttpGet("Dashboard/Logs/{channel}")]`, which seems a little silly since it should know what my Controller and Action are.

Comment: You are mapping to the default route, which would most likely have `id` . Show all your mapping and also include the controller definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mapping to the default convention based route, which would most likely have `{id}` as a route parameter. Because it maps to the default and you included `{channel}` it would add that parameter as a query string instead of part of the URL.

You would need to include a custom route for that action in order to get the desired URL generation.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Logs",
    pattern: "Dashboard/Logs/{channel}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Logs" });

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

and the necessary route values would need to be included so that it maps to the intended route

```
<a asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="Logs" asp-route-channel="@channel.Name">
     <button class="btn btn-success btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
</a>
```